# Вернуть значение с ajax js

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть такой код (`AJAX` jQuery):

```
    let Ajax = function (url, data, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: callback,
            complete: function () {},
            error: function (jqXHR) {

            }
        })
    };
```

Есть условие:

```
if(Ajax('site.ru/check', null, function(result) {
      return result.check
   })) {
    ...
} else {
    ....
}
```

Как мне вернуть значение из ajax, при том что ajax выполняется асинхронно?

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Это ассинхронный запрос и из него не получить результат привычными, для синхронного кода, методами.

```
Ajax(url, null, function(response) {
  if (response.check) {

  }
  else {

  }
});
```

Еще есть Promise, async, await, но там все делается иначе.

Comment: как в них иначе?

Comment: Ну, если осилите то вот: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function